# I get choppy sounds , and some buttons have to be clicked twice , and in the end sometimes It crashes

Tags: android

I am trying to play different sounds , when pressing different buttons , please scroll to the end as the declarations are big , I want the mediaplayer to destroy the file after it is done playing so when I click on another button , a whole new file is created and it doesnt play overlaping , I am using oncompletionlistner but it doesn't work , do I have it in a wrong place in the code ??

Here is the code : (please skip to the buttom)

```
package com.example.buttonsdemo;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    //Creating Sound arrays 
    //int i=0;
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new  MediaPlayer();
    Button button[] = new Button [120]; 
    int viewer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //first button
            final Button button_0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.akali);
            button_0.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Second button
            final Button button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alistar);
            button_1.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.ahri);
            button_2.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.amumu);
            button_3.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_4 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.anivia);
            button_4.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_5 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.annie);
            button_5.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_6 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.ashe);
            button_6.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_7 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.blitz);
            button_7.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_8 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.thresh);
            button_8.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_9 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.brand);
            button_9.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_10 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Caitlyn);
            button_10.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_11 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Cass);
            button_11.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_12 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.chogath);
            button_12.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_13 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Corki);
            button_13.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_14 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.darius);
            button_14.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_15 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.diana);
            button_15.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_16 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.draven);
            button_16.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_17 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.elise);
            button_17.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_18 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.eve);
            button_18.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_19 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.ezrael);
            button_19.setOnClickListener(this); 

            final Button button_20 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.fiddle);
            button_20.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_21 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.fiora);
            button_21.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_22 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.fizz);
            button_22.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_23 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.galio);
            button_23.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_24 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.garen);
            button_24.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_25 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.gp);
            button_25.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_26 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.gragas);
            button_26.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_27 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.graves);
            button_27.setOnClickListener(this);


            final Button button_50 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.maokai);
            button_50.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_51 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.mf);
            button_51.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_52 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.mordekaiser);
            button_52.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_53 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.morgana);
            button_53.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_54 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.mundo);
            button_54.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_55 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nami);
            button_55.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_56 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nasus);
            button_56.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_57 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nautilus);
            button_57.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_58 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nidalee);
            button_58.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_59 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nocturne);
            button_59.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_60 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.nunu);
            button_60.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_61 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.olaf);
            button_61.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_62 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.orianna);
            button_62.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_63 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.pantheon);
            button_63.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_64 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.poppy);
            button_64.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_65 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.quinn);
            button_65.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_66 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.rammus);
            button_66.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_67 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.renekton);
            button_67.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_68 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.rengar);
            button_68.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_69 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.riven);
            button_69.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_70 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.rumble);
            button_70.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_71 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.ryze);
            button_71.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_72 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sejuani);
            button_72.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_73 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.shaco);
            button_73.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_74 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.shen);
            button_74.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_75 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.shyvana);
            button_75.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_76 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.singed);
            button_76.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_77 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sion);
            button_77.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_78 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sivir);
            button_78.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_79 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.skarner);
            button_79.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_80 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sona);
            button_80.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_81 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.soraka);
            button_81.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_82 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.swain);
            button_82.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_83 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.syndra);
            button_83.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_84 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.talon);
            button_84.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_85 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.taric);
            button_85.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_86 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.teemo);
            button_86.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_87 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tf);
            button_87.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_88 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tristana);
            button_88.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_89 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.trundle);
            button_89.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_90 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.tryndamere);
            button_90.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_91 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.twitch);
            button_91.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_92 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.udyr);
            button_92.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_93 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.urgot);
            button_93.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_94 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.varus);
            button_94.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_95 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.vayne);
            button_95.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_96 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.veigar);
            button_96.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_97 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.viktor);
            button_97.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_98 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.vladimir);
            button_98.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_99 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.volibear);
            button_99.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_100 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.warwick);
            button_100.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_101 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.wukong);
            button_101.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_102 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.xerath);
            button_102.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_103 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.xinzhao);
            button_103.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_104 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.yi);
            button_104.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_105 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.yorick);
            button_105.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_106 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.zed);
            button_106.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_107 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.ziggs);
            button_107.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_108 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.zilean);
            button_108.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_109 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.zyra);
            button_109.setOnClickListener(this);

            final Button button_110 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.vi);
            button_110.setOnClickListener(this);








    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {

        case R.id.akali:
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.akali);
             viewer = R.layout.alistar;
            break;

        case R.id.alistar:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alistar);
            break;

        case R.id.ahri:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ahri);
                     break;
            case R.id.amumu:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.amumu);
                     break;
            case R.id.anivia:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.anivia);
                     break;
            case R.id.annie:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.annie);
                     break;
            case R.id.ashe:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ashe);
                     break;
            case R.id.blitz:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.blitzcrank);
                     break;
            case R.id.brand:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.brand);
                     break;
            case R.id.Caitlyn:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.caitlyn);
                     break;
            case R.id.Cass:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cassiopeia);
                     break;
            case R.id.chogath:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chogath);
                     break;
            case R.id.Corki:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.corki);
                     break;
            case R.id.darius:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.darius);
                     break;
            case R.id.diana:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.diana);
                     break;
            case R.id.draven:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.draven);
                     break;
            case R.id.elise:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.elise);
                     break;
            case R.id.eve:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.evelynn);
                     break;
            case R.id.ezrael:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ezreal);
                     break;
            case R.id.fiddle:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fiddlesticks);
                     break;
            case R.id.fiora:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fiora);
                     break;
            case R.id.fizz:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fizz);
                     break;
            case R.id.galio:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.galio);
                     break;
            case R.id.garen:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.garen);
                     break;
            case R.id.gp:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gangplank);
                     break;
            case R.id.gragas:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gragas);
                     break;
            case R.id.graves:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.graves);
                     break;
            case R.id.hecarim:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hecarim);
                     break;
            case R.id.heimer:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.heimerdinger);
                     break;
            case R.id.thresh:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.thresh);
                     break;
            case R.id.irelia :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. irielia);
                        break;
                case R.id.janna:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. janna);
                        break;
                case R.id.jarvan :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. jarvan);
                        break;
                case R.id.jax :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. jax);
                        break;
                case R.id.jayce :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jayce );
                        break;
                case R.id.karma :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.karma );
                        break;
                case R.id.karthus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.karthus );
                        break;
                case R.id. kassadin:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kassadin );
                        break;
                case R.id.katarina :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. katarina);
                        break;
                case R.id. kayle:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. kayle);
                        break;
                case R.id.kennen :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. kennen);
                        break;
                case R.id. khazix:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. khazix);
                        break;
                case R.id.kog :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kogmaw );
                        break;
                case R.id.leblanc :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. leblanc);
                        break;
                case R.id.leesin :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.leesin );
                        break;
                case R.id. leona:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. leona);
                        break;
                case R.id. lulu:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lulu );
                        break;
                case R.id.lux :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. lux);
                        break;
                case R.id.malphite :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.malphite );
                        break;
                case R.id. malzahar:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. malzahar);
                        break;
                case R.id.maokai :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mokai );
                        break;
                case R.id.mf :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.missfortune );
                        break;
                case R.id. mordekaiser:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. mordekaiser);
                        break;
                case R.id.morgana :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.morgana );
                        break;
                case R.id.mundo :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. drmundo);
                        break;
                case R.id.nami :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nami);
                        break;
                case R.id.nasus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nasus);
                        break;
                case R.id. nautilus:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nautilus );
                        break;
                case R.id. nidalee:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nidalee);
                        break;
                case R.id.nocturne :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nocturne);
                        break;
                case R.id.nunu :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nunu);
                        break;
                case R.id. olaf:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.olaf );
                        break;
                case R.id.orianna :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. orianna);
                        break;
                case R.id.pantheon :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. pantheon);
                        break;
                case R.id. poppy:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.poppy );
                        break;
                case R.id.quinn :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.quinn );
                        break;
                case R.id.rammus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. rammus);
                        break;
                case R.id.renekton :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. renekton);
                        break;
                case R.id. rengar:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. rengar);
                        break;
                case R.id. riven:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. riven);
                        break;
                case R.id.rumble:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.rumble );
                        break;
                case R.id.ryze :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ryze );
                        break;
                case R.id.sejuani :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sejuani);
                        break;
                case R.id.shaco :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shaco);
                        break;
                case R.id.shen :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shen);
                        break;
                case R.id.shyvana:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shyvana);
                        break;
                case R.id. singed:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.singed );
                        break;
                case R.id. sion:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sion );
                        break;
                case R.id. sivir:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sivir);
                        break;
                case R.id. skarner:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. skarner);
                        break;
                case R.id.sona :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sona);
                        break;
                case R.id. soraka:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.soraka );
                        break;
                case R.id.swain :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.swain );
                        break;
                case R.id.syndra :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.syndra );
                        break;
                case R.id. talon:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.talon );
                        break;
                case R.id.taric :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.taric );
                        break;
                case R.id.teemo :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.teemo );
                        break;
                case R.id. tf:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.twistedfate );
                        break;
                case R.id. tristana:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. tristana);
                        break;
                case R.id.trundle :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.trundle );
                        break;
                case R.id.tryndamere:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.tryndamere);
                        break;
                case R.id.twitch :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. twitch);
                        break;
                case R.id. udyr:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.udyr );
                        break;
                case R.id. urgot:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.urgot );
                        break;
                case R.id. varus:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. varus);
                        break;
                case R.id.vayne :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. vayne);
                        break;
                case R.id.veigar :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.veigar );
                        break;
                case R.id.viktor :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. viktor);
                        break;
                case R.id.vladimir :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vladimir );
                        break;
                case R.id.volibear :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.volibear);
                        break;
                case R.id.warwick :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.warwick );
                        break;
                case R.id.wukong :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. monkeyking);
                        break;
                case R.id.xerath :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.xerath );
                        break;
                case R.id.xinzhao :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. xinzhao);
                        break;
                case R.id.yi :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. masteryi);
                        break;
                case R.id.yorick :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yorick );
                        break;
                case R.id.zed :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zed );
                        break;
                case R.id.ziggs :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. ziggs);
                        break;
                case R.id.zilean :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zilean );
                        break;
                case R.id.zyra :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zyra );
                        break;
                case R.id.vi :
                 mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vi );
                        break;
        }

        mediaplayer.start();
        //setContentView(viewer);
        mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaplayer.release();


                }
            });
        }






      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          mediaplayer.release();
          super.onDestroy();
      }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Right before you press the other song

like here

```
 case R.id.zilean :
if(mediaplayer!=null)
 mediaplayer.release();
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zilean );
                        break;
```

Your Edited code

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {

            if(mediaplayer!=null)
            mediaplayer.release(); //------Just release it before any button ispressed.

        case R.id.akali:
            mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.akali);
             viewer = R.layout.alistar;
            break;

        case R.id.alistar:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alistar);
            break;

        case R.id.ahri:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ahri);
                     break;
            case R.id.amumu:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.amumu);
                     break;
            case R.id.anivia:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.anivia);
                     break;
            case R.id.annie:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.annie);
                     break;
            case R.id.ashe:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ashe);
                     break;
            case R.id.blitz:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.blitzcrank);
                     break;
            case R.id.brand:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.brand);
                     break;
            case R.id.Caitlyn:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.caitlyn);
                     break;
            case R.id.Cass:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cassiopeia);
                     break;
            case R.id.chogath:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chogath);
                     break;
            case R.id.Corki:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.corki);
                     break;
            case R.id.darius:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.darius);
                     break;
            case R.id.diana:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.diana);
                     break;
            case R.id.draven:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.draven);
                     break;
            case R.id.elise:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.elise);
                     break;
            case R.id.eve:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.evelynn);
                     break;
            case R.id.ezrael:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ezreal);
                     break;
            case R.id.fiddle:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fiddlesticks);
                     break;
            case R.id.fiora:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fiora);
                     break;
            case R.id.fizz:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fizz);
                     break;
            case R.id.galio:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.galio);
                     break;
            case R.id.garen:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.garen);
                     break;
            case R.id.gp:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gangplank);
                     break;
            case R.id.gragas:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.gragas);
                     break;
            case R.id.graves:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.graves);
                     break;
            case R.id.hecarim:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hecarim);
                     break;
            case R.id.heimer:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.heimerdinger);
                     break;
            case R.id.thresh:
            mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.thresh);
                     break;
            case R.id.irelia :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. irielia);
                        break;
                case R.id.janna:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. janna);
                        break;
                case R.id.jarvan :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. jarvan);
                        break;
                case R.id.jax :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. jax);
                        break;
                case R.id.jayce :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.jayce );
                        break;
                case R.id.karma :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.karma );
                        break;
                case R.id.karthus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.karthus );
                        break;
                case R.id. kassadin:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kassadin );
                        break;
                case R.id.katarina :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. katarina);
                        break;
                case R.id. kayle:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. kayle);
                        break;
                case R.id.kennen :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. kennen);
                        break;
                case R.id. khazix:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. khazix);
                        break;
                case R.id.kog :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.kogmaw );
                        break;
                case R.id.leblanc :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. leblanc);
                        break;
                case R.id.leesin :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.leesin );
                        break;
                case R.id. leona:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. leona);
                        break;
                case R.id. lulu:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lulu );
                        break;
                case R.id.lux :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. lux);
                        break;
                case R.id.malphite :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.malphite );
                        break;
                case R.id. malzahar:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. malzahar);
                        break;
                case R.id.maokai :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mokai );
                        break;
                case R.id.mf :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.missfortune );
                        break;
                case R.id. mordekaiser:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. mordekaiser);
                        break;
                case R.id.morgana :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.morgana );
                        break;
                case R.id.mundo :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. drmundo);
                        break;
                case R.id.nami :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nami);
                        break;
                case R.id.nasus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nasus);
                        break;
                case R.id. nautilus:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nautilus );
                        break;
                case R.id. nidalee:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nidalee);
                        break;
                case R.id.nocturne :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nocturne);
                        break;
                case R.id.nunu :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. nunu);
                        break;
                case R.id. olaf:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.olaf );
                        break;
                case R.id.orianna :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. orianna);
                        break;
                case R.id.pantheon :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. pantheon);
                        break;
                case R.id. poppy:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.poppy );
                        break;
                case R.id.quinn :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.quinn );
                        break;
                case R.id.rammus :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. rammus);
                        break;
                case R.id.renekton :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. renekton);
                        break;
                case R.id. rengar:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. rengar);
                        break;
                case R.id. riven:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. riven);
                        break;
                case R.id.rumble:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.rumble );
                        break;
                case R.id.ryze :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ryze );
                        break;
                case R.id.sejuani :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sejuani);
                        break;
                case R.id.shaco :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shaco);
                        break;
                case R.id.shen :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shen);
                        break;
                case R.id.shyvana:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. shyvana);
                        break;
                case R.id. singed:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.singed );
                        break;
                case R.id. sion:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sion );
                        break;
                case R.id. sivir:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sivir);
                        break;
                case R.id. skarner:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. skarner);
                        break;
                case R.id.sona :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. sona);
                        break;
                case R.id. soraka:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.soraka );
                        break;
                case R.id.swain :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.swain );
                        break;
                case R.id.syndra :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.syndra );
                        break;
                case R.id. talon:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.talon );
                        break;
                case R.id.taric :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.taric );
                        break;
                case R.id.teemo :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.teemo );
                        break;
                case R.id. tf:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.twistedfate );
                        break;
                case R.id. tristana:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. tristana);
                        break;
                case R.id.trundle :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.trundle );
                        break;
                case R.id.tryndamere:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.tryndamere);
                        break;
                case R.id.twitch :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. twitch);
                        break;
                case R.id. udyr:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.udyr );
                        break;
                case R.id. urgot:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.urgot );
                        break;
                case R.id. varus:
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. varus);
                        break;
                case R.id.vayne :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. vayne);
                        break;
                case R.id.veigar :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.veigar );
                        break;
                case R.id.viktor :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. viktor);
                        break;
                case R.id.vladimir :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vladimir );
                        break;
                case R.id.volibear :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.volibear);
                        break;
                case R.id.warwick :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.warwick );
                        break;
                case R.id.wukong :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. monkeyking);
                        break;
                case R.id.xerath :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.xerath );
                        break;
                case R.id.xinzhao :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. xinzhao);
                        break;
                case R.id.yi :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. masteryi);
                        break;
                case R.id.yorick :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.yorick );
                        break;
                case R.id.zed :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zed );
                        break;
                case R.id.ziggs :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw. ziggs);
                        break;
                case R.id.zilean :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zilean );
                        break;
                case R.id.zyra :
                mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.zyra );
                        break;
                case R.id.vi :
                 mediaplayer= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vi );
                        break;
        }

        mediaplayer.start();
        //setContentView(viewer);
        mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaplayer.release();


                }
            });
        }
```